# Error in cordova local notification

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, localnotification

I added Cordova-plugin-local-notification on my project(https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications).
and I added this code to the project

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
    title: 'My first notification',
    text: 'Thats pretty easy...',
    foreground: true
});
```

but it shows an error:

```
cordova is not defined
    at new MyApp
```

how can I fix this issue?
pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to, declare cordova like this,

```
declare var cordova: any;
```